# New Samsung ATIV Book 8 - looking for advice regarding linux installation

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot, uefi

I just bought a new laptop, Samsung ATIV Book 8, and I'm now researching how to approach installing linux alongside Windows 8.  Unfortunately I have been reading Samsungs have an issue with booting linux in UEFI.

Does anyone have any insight into my situation.

I hoped to install arch linux, but have been thinking Ubuntu might be a safer bet.  Any advice or recommendations?

**EDIT:** It turns out that the option for legacy mode is not visible until Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: I highly doubt it doesn't have UEFI, and Secure Boot AFAIK can't exist with legacy BIOS. Can you post some snapshots of your BIOS/UEFI screens? Also, do you see options for turning off SB? Check nearby if you see an option to enable legacy BIOS or Compatibility Support Module (CSM).

Comment: You can post links and someone can add the images for you. Also, do not post duplicates on multiple SE sites: http://askubuntu.com/questions/319508

Comment: I deleted my answer because it turns out you just needed to disable secure boot before the CSM option becomes visible.  I feel so stupid.

Comment: Please simply answer your own question if you have the solution. Also, please delete the Ask Ubuntu variant. Thanks!

Comment: Well there you have it. Turns out my suspicion that the support rep was a typically useless exemplar of his ilk was spot on. It *is* UEFI after all, SB doesn't exist in conjunction with legacy BIOS, and all is right with the world again. :) Now as for whether it is safe for you to install Linux, I would say go for it but it's up to you to take the chance and trust Samsung has completely fixed the bug...